How to restream on twitch trough my nginx-rtmp server with twitch vod track function?
I've been trying days to get twitch vod track feature working while restreaming my obs stream trough nginx-rtmp server running on my raspberry pi, but i can't still manage how to do it or if it's even possible.
I am restreaming mainly because of "fallback video" feature on my nginx-rtmp server (i can add or remove delay while the stream continues) but that doesn't allow me to split audio (to live / vod)
Seems like it's not possible, otherwise i believe, that restreaming platforms like restream.io would have that implemented already, but i want to find a solution somehow.
Is there a possibility to stream 2 audio tracks into my raspberry pi from obs? (i've found this plugin which maybe allows me to do so: https://github.com/ratwithacompiler/OBS-multitrack-stream
but when viewing my stream in nginx, seems like there is only one audio track available (most likely rtmp-nginx stream can't do 2 audio tracks). So i enabled HLS to be able to receive 2 audio tracks, but still no luck.
Am i somehow able to stream to twitch from my own rtmp server and keep the twitch vod track function running? Does anyone have any idea?
